# Is cancelling pending API request on route change a good approach in Angular? Not being able to display a title with translate pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

http-cancel-interceptor.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpCancelService } from '../service/http-cancel.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpCancelInterceptorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private httpCancelService: HttpCancelService) { }

  intercept<T>(req: HttpRequest<T>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(takeUntil(this.httpCancelService.onCancelPendingRequests()))
  }
}
```

http-cancel.service.ts

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpCancelService {

  private cancelPendingRequests$ = new Subject<void>()

  constructor() { }

  /** Cancels all pending Http requests. */
  public cancelPendingRequests() {
    this.cancelPendingRequests$.next()
  }

  public onCancelPendingRequests() {
    return this.cancelPendingRequests$.asObservable()
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpCancelInterceptorInterceptor, multi: true },
]
```

app.component.ts

```
 if (routerEvent instanceof ActivationEnd) {
     // this.httpCancelService.cancelPendingRequests()
 }
```

I have used the above codes and am able to cancel the pending requests on route change. But the problem is the title with `| translate` is not visible in the HTML template. It is visible if I use `NavigationStart` event instead of the `ActivationEnd` event.